# Why does ~pd.isnull() return -2?

Tags: python

I was doing some quick tests for handling missing values and came across this weird behavior. When looking at `~pd.isnull(np.nan)`, I expect it to return False, but instead it returns -2. Why is this?

Comment: Your tests will be more valuable if you carefully analyze types of data you test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is warranted, because this strange result for a *scalar* is inconsistent with the result you would see when "inverting" a logical array:

```
>>> pd.isnull([np.nan])
array([ True])
>>> ~pd.isnull([np.nan])
array([False])
```

There are a few weird things in play here. Note that:

```
>>> pd.isnull(np.nan)
True
```

So, taking numpy and pandas out of the question, you're essentially asking why:

```
>>> ~True
-2
```

This happens because `bool` is a subclass of `int`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

The expression `~x` hooks into the datamodel [`type(x).__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__). Now, `bool` doesn't implement `__invert__` so it falls back to the first superclass who does, i.e. `int`:

```
>>> int.__invert__(True)
-2
```

For [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), `~x` is essentially computing `-(x+1)`. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) actually define it as such.

Unfortunately, it would not be easy for `bool` to override `__invert__` in a more sensible way, i.e. for `~b` to return the same result as `not b`, whilst still maintaining the backwards compatibility guarantee that bools *are* ints.  You would end up with a troubling special-case where `x == y` but `~x != ~y`.

Comment: Ah, this makes perfect sense now, thank you. Combining your answer with @CiaPan 's answer brings it all together on how to write better tests.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used an arithmetic, bitwie negation operator instead of a logical negation.